How to load a webassembly file directly in android JavaScriptSandbox using JS
I am trying to use webassembly from assets folder inside android. I have this working test code:
suspend fun runWebAssembly(): Result<String> = runCatchingCo {
    val isolate = getSandbox().createIsolate()

    val resources = applicationContext.resources
    val inputStream = resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test).createInputStream()
    val addTwoWasm = inputStream.readBytes()
    val jsCode = "(async ()=>{" +
            "const wasm = await android.consumeNamedDataAsArrayBuffer('wasm_1');" +
            "const module = await WebAssembly.compile(wasm);" +
            "const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module);" +
            "return instance.exports.addTwo(20, 22).toString();" +
            "})()"

    isolate.provideNamedData("wasm_1", addTwoWasm)
    isolate.evaluateJavaScriptAsync(jsCode).await().also {
        isolate.close()
    }
}

The problem is that the desired webassembly files will be quite huge (30mb) and I would like to omit loading them in kotlin and directly load them into js code. The problem is that none of the nodes like eg. fetch are available, and import does not seem to work (is not defined).
"const wasm = await fetch('file:///android_asset/test.wasm');" //Does not work

Is there a way to either add somehow the missing dependencies to use fetch or something similar, or maybe other way to load those files ?

the JavaScript engine in Android's WebView (which is used by the androidx.webkit library) doesn't have access to the file system or network by default. This is a security feature to prevent malicious scripts from accessing sensitive data.
class WebAssemblyLoader(private val context: Context) {
    fun loadWasmFile(filename: String): ByteArray {
        val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test).createInputStream()
        return inputStream.readBytes()
    }
}

val webView = WebView(context)
webView.addJavaScriptInterface(WebAssemblyLoader(context), "WebAssemblyLoader")

val jsCode = """
    const wasm = WebAssemblyLoader.loadWasmFile('test.wasm');
    const module = await WebAssembly.compile(wasm);
    const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module);
    return instance.exports.addTwo(20, 22).toString();
"""

